# Editing the nav menu?

Tags: menus, navigation

I want to add | (vertical lines) between the page links in the nav menu.  What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: This would be a CSS question. You can use left/right borders to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wp_nav_menu` function supports multiple styling parameters, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

For instance you can add a `$menu_id` and then style the CSS for each `<li>` along the lines of `border-right:1px solid;` . Another option is to just add a "|" for the `$link_after` parameter, but you should probably use the ascii HTML entity value for it which is `&#124;`.

Comment: Thanks, I want it to be a "|" because I like the way the font I'm using for the nav displays it. However, if I add a $menu_id I get a "|" at the end of the menu, plus it also become part of the link so changes color on rollover. Any ideas?

Comment: Use an background image if you want a specific look.